# How to create a 2D list in python where all elements are the same?

Tags: python, list

I want to create a `n x n` 2D list of lists in python, where all elements are equal to `False`. So I tried this:

```
array = [[False] * n] * n
```

This appears to give me what I want, but if I want to change an element in the `(i, j)` position, say:

```
array[i][j] = not array[i][j]
```

this changes all the elements in the j<sup>th</sup> column, rather than just affecting `(i, j)` position. I realize this is because all the rows in the list are just referencing the first row.

Is there a non verbose way in vanilla python (no numpy) to create a 2D list of lists without the internal referencing (is that what it's called) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension.

```
array = [[False for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
```

See here:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> n = 10
>>> array = [[False for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
>>> pprint(array)
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Now if you want to change an element at (i, j), you can just assign to it:

```
>>> array[2][4] = True
>>> pprint(array)

[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: It would be more pythonic to use anonymous variables instead of x, thus  `array = [[False for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]` as you do not use `x` in the expressions.

Comment: also if you try to iterate oves **values** of array (which you do) you could just use `for row in array: print row` instead of any indexing (cleaner and simplier); or even more pythonic - import pprint from pprint and pprint the whole array: `from pprint import pprint; pprint(array)`

Comment: Never heard of `pprint`. Thanks @lejlot!

Comment: Anonymous variables seem nice. Not to mention `pprint` and List comprehension! Thanks for the tips.